# How to use matrix entries in a double symsum?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement the following double summation in a function:

`f(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^{S}\sum_{l=0}^{S}{a_{kl}x^ky^l}`.

Here is my first attempt:

```
function [ a ] = MyFun( S )
a=randi([0 9],S+1);
syms x y k l;
f(x,y)=symsum(symsum(a(k,l)*x^k*y^l,l,1,S+1),k,1,S+1);
f(1,2)
end
```

Actually, my code evaluates `f` in a loop later on, but that does not seem relevant here. Trying something like `MyFun(3)` results in an error:

> Error using sym/subsindex (line 766) Invalid indexing or function
>   definition. When defining a function, ensure that the arguments are
>   symbolic variables and the body of the function is a SYM expression.
>   When indexing, the input must be numeric, logical, or ':'.
>
> Error in MyFun (line 4)
>   f(x,y)=symsum(symsum(a(k,l)*x^(k-1)*y^(l-1),l,1,S+1),k,1,S+1);

Everything works fine if `a(k,l)*` is removed from the inner `symsum`, so I suspect that there is something wrong with the indices. Is it not possible to use the symbolical variables `k` and `l` as indices? If not, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing a matrix using a symbolic value does not seem to work. As an alternative you can use elementwise multiplication as follows:

```
function f = MyFun( S )
    a=randi([0 9],S+1);
    k = repmat((0:S)', 1, S+1);
    l = repmat((0:S), S+1, 1);
    syms x y;
    f(x, y) = sum(sum(a .* x.^k .* y.^l));
end
```