# Series-function with vector-coefficients in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a vector v and would like to define a function `x` using following formular:
[image: Formular for the Matlab-Command]

Now I try to define this in Matlab, but for some reason I can't access an array within a symsum.

```
v = [1 2 3 4];
syms k
x = @(t) symsum(v(k) * exp(2*pi*i*k*t/size(v)), k, 1, size(x_n));
```

When I try to evaluate this Function `x(4)` I get an exception:

```
Error using sym/subsindex (line 796)
Invalid indexing or function definition. When defining a function, ensure that the arguments are
symbolic variables and the body of the function is a SYM expression. When indexing, the input
must be numeric, logical, or ':'.
```

Do you know, why? Do you have a solution or workaround?

Comment: Deleted my answer. Dig into how you declared your function. https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use matrix entries in a double symsum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43706817/how-to-use-matrix-entries-in-a-double-symsum)

Comment: I think the problem is that you can't mix vector indexing with the symbolic operations inside the function.